# PHP TDD and CI. Good talks/books?

Tags: php, tdd, continuous-integration

Do you guys recommend any books, videos or talks on TDD and CI for PHP?

Comment: I would think any books on the subject should be language agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend "[Real-World Solutions for Developing High-Quality PHP Frameworks and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470872497)" by Sebastian Bergmann (The creator of PHPUnit).

Also "[xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054)" is pretty good, not PHP specific though.